# Django Error migrating db from SQLite to Postgres

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I developed a site locally with SQLite and I am getting an error while attempting to migrate to Postgres for production.

The error is

```
File "/Users/______/Desktop/______/accounts/models.py", line 46, in user_addgroup_handler
    name=(instance.business_location_county.name + ' ' + instance.business_location_state.name), forum_id=instance.business_location_county.id)


AttributeError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/_____/Desktop/_______/data1.json': 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The relevant model is:

```
if created:
    
    new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(
        name=(instance.business_location_county.name + ' ' + instance.business_location_state.name), forum_id=instance.business_location_county.id)
```

To create the dump file I ran:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --naturalprimary -e contentypes -e auth.Permission --indent 2 > data1.json
```

Any ideas about what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: I faced the same issue, and I remember end up doing the `dumpdata table` one by one for each table.

Comment: I tried attempting to migrate single tables and I am getting the same error for this model.

Comment: Ultimately I was able to get the db migrated by running dumpdata for each table and  loading them in an order that prevented errors (ex some tables depended on data in other tables). Also commands in the format 'python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --naturalprimary -e contentypes -e auth.Permission --indent 2 > data1.json" did not work when attempting to load the fixtures. Simple "python manage.py dumpdata  auth.Permission --indent 2 > data1.json" worked